# Prevent IDEA nullability warning when array elements are allowed to be null?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have this `package-info.java` at my root package for the project:

```
/**
 In this project, parameters are assumed to be non-null by default.
 If a parameter may be null, you should annotate it with `@Nullable`.
 This file added to tell IDEA about our nullability approach.
 `ParametersAreNonnullByDefault` specifies this approach, but apparently only
 works at the package level, but DefaultQualifier specifies `Nonnull` for all
 packages underneath.
 */
@DefaultQualifier(Nonnull.class)
@javax.annotation.ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
package kopi.apisvc;

import org.checkerframework.framework.qual.DefaultQualifier;

import javax.annotation.Nonnull;
```

The following demonstration code is an example of the problem, I do not want to change the behavior of the code, I just want IDEA to not show a warning.  I do not want to refactor to using an `Optional<>`, nor use something like `Objects.nonNull()` which would change the behavior of the code.

```
  public static void doSomething(){
    @Nullable String value = null;
    var formattedValue = formatThing("", value);
    System.out.println(formattedValue);
  }

  public static String formatThing(Object... elements){
    // implementation that handles null value array elements properly
  }
```

IntelliJ IDEA displays a warning saying `Passing 'null' argument to parameter annotated as @NotNull` when a null value is passed to the formatThing() method. However, this is not a concern because the method is designed to handle null values for its elements.

How do I tell IDEA that the element values of the array are allowed to be null?

Adding `@Nullable` to the declaration of elements is not a valid answer because:

- it indicates that the array itself may be null (which is not the intention)
- it doesn't solve the problem anyway - IDEA still displays the warning.

I do not want to add suppression warnings everywhere I call the method with possible null elements.

---

Versions

- Java: 21
- IntelliJ IDEA: 2023.3.3

Comment: Does it help if you write the method invocation as `formatThing(new Object[] { "", value })`?

Comment: Whether that helps or not, this looks like a flaw in IDEA to me.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: it gives a different (better, I think?) warning message:
`'null' is stored to an array of @NotNull elements`.

As far as I can tell, neither IDEA (nor even Java, really) support the ability to declare that an array may contain null elements.

Comment: It's curious that the diagnostic messages refer to `@NotNull` when you are using JSR-305 annotations, given that that is not the spelling (`@Nonnull`) used by JSR-305.  I don't know whether that is significant.  I also don't know whether it is `@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault` or `@DefaultQualifier(Nonnull.class)` or both (or neither) that is causing the issue, but that would be worth figuring out.  If it's `@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault` only, then presumably it can be overridden by annotating that one method with `@ParametersAreNullableByDefault`.

Comment: When you tried applying `@Nullable` to the method parameter, are sure it was `@javax.annotations.Nullable`?  There are others that you might plausibly have used, and chances are good that you need to choose one from the same collection as the relevant `@Nonnull` (or `@NotNull`) annotation if you want to counteract it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger It was `@DefaultQualifier` - thankyou.
You were right about the annotation package too, but it didn't seem to make a difference.  In this project, I seem to be using the `jakarta` annotations everywhere, rather than `javax` (I have no recollection of why I'm doing that though).  So I did need to change my defaults to specify that, for correctness (but it seems IDEA treats the annotations interchangeably).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to `John Bollinger` for putting me on the right track - the trick is to reset the defaults for the method of interest.

Just for this one method where I want the elements to be nullable, set the `@DefaultQualifier` to be nullable, then explicitly set the input/output parameters to be non-null:

```
  @DefaultQualifier(Nullable.class)
  public static @Nonnull String formatThing(@Nonnull Object... elements){
    // implementation that handles null value array elements properly
    return "";
  }
```